# Can't link the MinHook library

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, linker-errors

I keep getting

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MH_CreateHook@12 referenced
>   in function _DllMain@12

yet I put

```
#include "MinHook.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"libMinHook.x64.lib")
```

and have the locations to include and libs set

The library can be downloaded from here https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=44326

or from https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook

I have even compiled the source and yet the same problem :/

Comment: Are you building a 64 bit application since you are linking to a 64 bit library?

Comment: Yes I am.I need MinHook because the Detours one from MS is 10 grand.

Comment: Wait a second, I did not put at Configuration Properties the x64 platform, i tought its auto.I only have Win32

Comment: Thank you , it works now.I had to compile for x64.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are building your application as a 64 bit application if you are using a x64 library. You can not use a 64 bit library with a 32 bit application.